# Is there any way to create a virtual Speaker or Mic in C#?

Tags: audio, virtual-drive

And then the final Speaker/Mic can be specified through the api.

Or I should ask, what is more reasonable to describe the technology or product that can do this?

Comment: What OS?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Brad Win10+,  what I am trying to do should be Virtual Audio Cable

Comment: If that's what you need to do, then you'll need to license one of the virtual audio cable drivers.  If instead you just need to capture from some other application, you can use WASAPI.

Comment: @Brad Thank you very much for your reply. In fact, my purpose is to switch Skype communication devices, but I tried to set the default communication devices of the system, and I found that this will not switch the communication devices of Skype. So I think maybe I can add VAC between Skype and devices to achieve my purpose. But can I use WASAPI to capture the audio stream of one device and output it to another device?

Comment: If Skype is set up to use the default communications audio capture device, I'm surprised that changing the system's default device wouldn't change Skype.  Sounds like a Skype bug, honestly.  (Or, a "feature". :-) )  Isn't there some API for Skype?  Perhaps on the broadcasting version.

Comment: Yes, honestly I also think this is a skype (for business) bug, but I have to try to fix this problem because the response I got in the skype community is that they currently have no plans to provide such apis. :)

Comment: And Sorry, the method I just mentioned should only apply to virtual audio device, not physical audio device, right? Because it may involve the privacy of users?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the end goal?  What does your software do?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. My software is used with USB headset. When the user uses the headset (for example, AirPods takes out the headset), I need to switch the default device (and default communication device) to USB headset. Normally, this is perfect, but when Skype or teams are in a call, switching the windows default communication device does not work for them.

Comment: A virtual sound card sounds way more complex and potentially issue prone than perhaps filing a bug report on Skype.  Maybe another option is to take whatever the current device is and disable it so that Skype is forced to reset audio capture?

Comment: Thanks, I will continue to try to report this bug to Skype(or Teams). In addition, your idea is great, when I try to switch the communication device of Skype to PC Speaker, disabling the USB audio device is indeed effective. But if I try to switch the Skype communication device to USB audio, enabling the device or switching the default device will not work.